# Python script works alone but no such file when run through nodejs child process

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

```
Error, could not create TXT output file: No such file or directory

tesseract ./downloads/en.jpg outputs/1585336201.287781output -l eng
```

is the error i'm having trouble with, this command works fine from the python script but not through a childprocess spawn, downloads and the .py script are in the same folder, and both of them are in a folder next to the nodejs script

this is the method that i call from a post function to give it the imagine fine that i need to transcribe, then the python script can't run the tesseract command, even though it can do it when its run manually

```
const verif = async (fileName, filePath) => {

    var uint8arrayToString = function(data){
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
    };

    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

    const scriptExecution = spawn('python',['-u', './diploma/app.py']);

    var data = JSON.stringify([fileName]);
    scriptExecution.stdin.write(data);
    scriptExecution.stdin.end();

    scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(uint8arrayToString(data));
    });

    scriptExecution.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        // As said before, convert the Uint8Array to a readable string.
        console.log(uint8arrayToString(data));
    });

    scriptExecution.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log("Process quit with code : " + code);
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that tesseract needed windows permissions when executed from the js file